# Regex Match string with non-alphanumberic chars from a binary file

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to extract some information from a binary file. It looks like this:

`AUTHCODE(here goes 3 bytes, that I don't need)part_that_i_need(here goes a NULL byte)`.

[image]

How to I match the portion of alpha-numeric characters `qszjlbnkmctkkezgd_qyzkyptqigudilzpkp_qgetefvmigwimrihudk` that is between bytes {11} {00} {38} and {00}.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
            string ReadFileMF;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pathCopy))
            {
                ReadFileMF = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            ///match the whole string
            Match passMF = Regex.Match(ReadFileMF, @"(AUTHCODE).+?(www)");
            String passMFs = passMF.Value;

            //convert to array of bytes
            byte[] bpass = StrToByteArray(passMFs);

            //replace the 3 bytes after AUTHCODE with spaces
            bpass[8] = 0x20;
            bpass[9] = 0x20;
            bpass[10] = 0x20;
```

Ok, so now I have just to match the nullbyte at the end. Somthing like `(AUTHCODE).+?(NULL_BYTE)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can the lengths change? Can you safely turn it into a string first (you mention regex).

Comment: yes the length of the value I need can change. And it is already turned into a string that matches (AUTHCODE).+?(N)

Comment: "it is already turned into a string" - that means you want to skip `char`s, not `byte`s.

Comment: You'll definitely want to use `new StreamReader(pathCopy, Encoding.ASCII)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be easiest with a few simple for-loops or Copy() actions over the byte data. Too few specs to be exact. Like:

```
// untested, I could be off-by-1 somewhere
int start = "AUTHCODE".Length + 3;
int end = text.Indexof('\0', start);
string result = text.SubString(start, end-start);
```

If you do want/need Regex, you'll have to turn it into a string first. Your only safe bet seems to be ASCII encoding.

```
 string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
```

and then (untested)

```
 Regex.Match(text, "AUTHCODE.{3}([^\0x00]+)\0x00);
```

Comment: i don't need to amtch those 3 bytes, but the part that is between them and the null byte

Comment: Which is what `([^\0x00]+)` ought to math (the first and only group)